# Avoiding UnicodeDecodeError exceptions Python

Tags: python

In python I use an html template to display a steam player's information.

The template is:

```
'''<td>
<div>
Name: %s<br>
Hours: %s<br>
<a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/%s" target="_blank">Steam Profile</a> <br>
</div>
</td>'''
```

So I have TEMPLATE %(personaName, tf2Hours, id64)

Later on that template is saved into an html file.

Occasionally it returns a UnicodeDecodeError, because personaName can contain strange characters.

Is there a way to avoid this while still having the correct characters in the final html file?

EDIT:

The reason for the error was non-unicode characters.

Doing unicode(personaName, errors='ignore') solved the issue.

Comment: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 u'UnicodeTextHereaあä'.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

This will ignore unicode characters that can't be converted to ascii.

Here are a few examples that I just tried.

```
>>> x = 'Hello world!'
>>> y = 'notあä ascii'
>>> x.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
b'Hello world!'
>>> y.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
b'not ascii'
```

As you can see, it removed every trace of non-ascii characters.

---

Alternatively, you could tell the interpreter that you are planning on reading unicode values. For example (from [docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html)),

```
with open('unicode.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(repr(line))
```

This will interpret and allow you to read unicode as-is.

Comment: 'Dawn â™ˆ Of â™ˆ The â™ˆ Dusk'.encode('ascii', 'ignore') Returns an error. I have absolutely no idea why and it is really frustrating D:

Comment: How about this?  `line.decode('utf-8', 'ignore').encode('ascii', 'ignore')`